# How to retrieve the standard output and error of an SSIS process task

Tags: c#, ssis

**The context:**
I have an SSIS package which call a C# Console application via an Execute Process Task.

[image]

The C# program use `Console.Write("xxx");` and `Console.Error.Write("yyyy");` to tell if it works properly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //do stuff
                Console.Write("xxx");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Error.Write("yyyy");
            }
        }
```

**My question:**
How to capture the output of the process task in ssis?

**What I have tried :**

Setting StandardOutputVariable and StandardErrorVariable in the process task expression with local variable in control flow.

[image]

When I defined String variables, both are empty after the process task finished.
When I defined Object variables, I tried to run a script task and cast the Value as String array but it throw an invalid cast exception.

What I am missing?
I can't modify the real C# program to change the way it logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself by experimenting.

Ok what I was missing is how the expressions value for standardErrorVariable works.

When I fill the standardErrorVariable expression value with a variable, the behavior is:

**`use the value of @[User::l_output] as a variable name to use for standardOutput.`**

It is not : *`use this variable to capture the output`*

So I have 2 solutions to capture the output of my process:

1. Directly use the `@[User::l_output]` in the process task configuration (not in espression tab)
2. Use the `@[User::l_output]` variable in the StandardOutputVariable expression and set my variable value an other name of variable I previously declared.
   [image]

Comment: How did you find @[User::l_output] variable name ? by experimenting ?!!

Comment: the variable name @[User::l_output] has no importance here. I prefixed the name with L for local variable or P for parameter of the ssis pacakge

Comment: it is not clear for me. Could you show an image using the variables